# Heroku Deployment not working with MongoDb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, deployment

I created one demo app with ReactJS, NodeJS, MongoDb and Express. Trying to deploy on heroku. It works fine, if i dont use mongo, but as soon as i introduced mongo db. I am getting error cannot GET /.
I am using mongodb atlas. Do I need heroku addon to use database?

server.js

```
// Import dependencies
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const fs = require('fs');
const moment = require("moment");

require('dotenv').config();

const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.xzzno.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const DATABASE_NAME = "DBNAME";
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


const app = express();

// Set our backend port to be either an environment variable or port 5000

// This application level middleware prints incoming requests to the servers console, useful to see incoming requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Request_Endpoint: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    next();
});

// Configure the bodyParser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// Configure the CORs middleware
app.use(cors());

app.get("/test/", (request, response) => {
    response.send({"name":"Hello Test!!!"});
});





var database, userSignUp;

app.listen(port, () => {
    MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
        if(error) {
            throw error;
        }
        database = client.db(DATABASE_NAME);
        userSignUp = database.collection("UserData");
        
       
        console.log("Connected to `" + DATABASE_NAME + "`!");
       
    
    });
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning Deployment",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\"",
    "client:build": "cd client && npm run build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Username/TestProject.git"
  },
  "author": "Ankita Jaiswal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Username/TestProject/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Username/TestProject#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.8"
  }
}
```

procfile

web: npm run dev

have tried web: npm start as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just from my limited experience, I've had the same issue and it turned out I forgot to configure my environment variables on Heroku, so my MONGO_URI was undefined.  If not that, you can use the Heroku CLI and run `heroku logs --tail` from the root of your project and might be able to see more about what's going on.

Comment: Its not undefined. I am getting only error "cannot get /"

Comment: Did you use mlab or objectrocket addon of heroku? or had any paid account of heroku?

Comment: I should have been more specific.  The error I got didn't say my environment variable was undefined, but I suspect that because it was undefined my app crashed and I also got a 'cannot GET' error.  I used standard free tier MongoDB Atlas and standard free tier Heroku. No addons.  Also, try removing/adding quotation marks around the MONGO_URI variable in the Heroku configuration.  I forget, but I don't think you need quotation marks. Make sure there are no spaces, etc..

Comment: can you please share server.js, directory structure, package.json and mongo_uri cmd. on my mail ankitajaiswal2890@gmail.com

Comment: This project is deployed and working. The relevant code is here. https://github.com/Perrottarichard/pizzapizza-server/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Some notable differences I see are you're using MongoClient to connect, whereas I'm using mongoose.  Also, your procfile has npm run dev, whereas I'm using node index.js (you would use node server.js)  What do your heroku logs say? They should include a more specific error message

Comment: I also noticed, you're serving something from "/test/" but not from "/"

Comment: does that make any difference using mongoclient instead of mongoose? I am calling /test in app.js in reactapp. It is working if i remove mongo part.

Comment: I don't know, I've never connected via mongoclient.  Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Just for my own information, I'm curious...what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.xzzno.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

The upper code is incorrect. You have to change < username > and < password > (both include < >) by your usename and your password! Example:

```
const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb+srv://kanechan25:kane02052409@cluster0.xzzno.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```